# Upper bound implied by the Chebyshev bound

Tags: statistics, random-variables

> Suppose that X is a random variable with expectation 5 and variance 1/2. Then what is an upper bound implied by the Chebyshev bound on the the probability that X is not strictly between 4 and 6?

I know that the Chebyshev's formula is var(x)/c^2, but I'm confused as to what this formula gives me. Is the question asking for a value for the upper bound, or the probability that X will exceed the upper bound? And how do I find both of those things?

Answer (score 2):

Your variable $X$ has the mean $\mu=5$ and the variance $\sigma^2 = 0.5$. It is not between $4$ and $6$ if and only if $|X-\mu | > 1 = \sqrt{2}\cdot\frac1{\sqrt{2}}$. Chebyshev inequality states exactly what we want

$$\Pr\left(|X-\mu |\geq k\sigma\right) \leq {\frac {1}{k^{2}}}.$$

In our case we have

$$\Pr\left(|X-5 |\geq \sqrt{2}\cdot\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\right) \leq {\frac {1}{2}}.$$

So, what does it actually mean? It means that the probability of $X$ being in external of $[4,6]$ is **less** than $\frac12$. Or, at the same time, the probability of $X$ being within $[4,6]$ is **at least** $\frac12$.

Is it clearer for you now?

Comment: Makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Chebyshev tells us that $P(|X-\mu|≥k\sigma) \,≤\,\frac {1}{k^2}$.

Here, you want  an estimate on $P(|X-5|≥1)$.  But $\sigma = \frac {1}{\sqrt 2}$ so $1=\sqrt 2\times \sigma$  Thus we can take $k=\sqrt 2$ and deduce that $$P(|X-5|≥1)\,≤\,\frac 12$$